# My react app redirects to wrong component before loading the right component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a react app connected to firebase that has 3 roles. Admin, user, and tutor. I have added the code to check the role on sign in and redirect appropriately based on the role. However, even when I login as user, I can see that the app first loads the admin page (log statements from admin component printed ) and then redirects to the user component. If I logout and then login as an author now, first the admin component is mounted, then the user component and finally I land on the author component. I am identifying this via `console.log` statements.

The code is as below.

```
export default function LoginSignup() { 
    const signIn = async (e) => { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if (email && password) { 
            await signInWithEmailAndPassword(firebaseAuth, email, password) 
                .then(async (user) => { 
                    const q = query(userCollection, where("email", "==", email)); 
                    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q); 
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { 
                        console.log("//////////////" + doc.data().role);
                        setRole(doc.data().role); 
                        setUser(user.user);
                        if (doc.data().role == "admin") {
                          navigate("/admin");
                        } else if (doc.data().role == "user") {
                          navigate("/user");
                        } else if (doc.data().role == "author") {
                          navigate("/author");
                        } else {
                          console.log("role undefined");
                        }
                      });
                })
                .catch(async (error) => {
                      alert(error)
                });
                handlerEmail("");
                handlerPassword("");
          }
        }; 
}
```

```
export default function AdminDashboard() { 
    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(firebaseAuth, (currentUser) => {
            if (currentUser) {
                console.log("admin dash");
                setUser(currentUser);
            } else 
                navigate("/");
        });
    }, []); 
}
```

When I log in as an admin I am redirected to admin dash, no problems there. Next when I log in as a user, the console statement from admin dash is first printed and then `"//////////////" + user"` (log statement from loginsignup.jsx) is printed and then user dashboard component is loaded.

It is an issue only if I login with other roles before. If I first login as user then this doesn't occur.

Logged in as admin, logged out, then logged in as user. First `useEffect()` of admin component was triggered before loading the user component.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the user and role state when the user signs out:

```
export default function AdminDashboard() { 
    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(firebaseAuth, (currentUser) => {
            if (currentUser) {
                console.log("admin dash");
                setUser(currentUser);
            } else {
                setUser(undefined); //  or whatever indicates that there is no user to your app
                setRole(""); //  or whatever value indicates no role
                navigate("/");
            }
        });
    }, []); 
}
```

Without clearing the role, the new user will initially have the previous user's role - until you've loaded their own role value from the database.